# Flutter 2: webview_flutter & model_viewer

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, model-viewer

I'm trying to implement google's model_viewer into my app. Following the [Demo Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aDnC.png), i'm not able to get it to work:

doing: flutter run: gives following error:

> /Users/felixjungo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:367:23:
> warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' is
> deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
> In module 'WebKit' imported from /Users/felixjungo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfigura
> tion.h:211:28: note: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @property (nonatomic) BOOL mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback",
> ios(8.0, 9.0));
> ^
> /Users/felixjungo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:374:23:
> warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' is
> deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
> In module 'WebKit' imported from /Users/felixjungo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfigura
> tion.h:211:28: note: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @property (nonatomic) BOOL mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback",
> ios(8.0, 9.0));
> ^

model_viewer is depending on webview_flutter ^0.3.22 so i'm using

> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

to run it because of the old version of the webview widget. I get following error:

> Xcode's output:
> lib/main.dart:105:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'src'. src:
> 'https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb',
>
> lib/main.dart:86:7: Context: The class 'ModelViewer' has a constructor
> that takes no arguments. class ModelViewer extends StatelessWidget {
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code note:
> Using new build system note: Building targets in parallel note:
> Planning build note: Analyzing workspace note: Constructing build
> description note: Build preparation complete
> .../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment
> target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
> 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

pubspec.yalm:

environment:
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
model_viewer: ^0.8.1

---

main.dart:

import 'package:model_viewer/model_viewer.dart';

---

Can i force model_viewer to use a new version of webview?
Does somebody have a clue what could be the problem?
I do not get any errors if i delete the ModelViewer Widget from my code, but leave the importer there.

[model_viewer is legacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aDnC.png)

Comment: Upvoted. I'm also looking for this one

Comment: if you fork the model_viewer widget you can upgrade the dependencies in the pup.yalm file and it will run in the "no sound null savety" mode!

But i guess it is almost easier to create a webview widget and load googles model_viewer over a URL to your webserver, where you host your models.

What i don't get: wich one is better: flutter webview, in app webview or the webview plugin? My main Problem is performace and startup time.

Comment: + i can get the model_viewer to work but it is not showing the AR Butoon on my iPhone. What is the "Browser" if you surf the web with the webview widget?